# Trying to get to load a React Image, from a JSon String

Tags: javascript, json, material-ui

[image]

I am trying to load the pictures from a JSON file that I have loaded. But for some reason, it keeps giving me this error, Cannot find module '../../static/images/Jstar.jpg'

```
import WorkExperiences from "../../Scripts/Json/WorkExperiences.json";

<CardMedia
  component="img"
  height="194"
  image= {require(WorkExperiences.pastExperiences[0].pictures[0])}
  alt= {WorkExperiences.pastExperiences[0].companyName}
/>
```

This is when I use a JSON file to try to load the image, but when I straight use a string

```
<CardMedia
  component="img"
  height="194"
  image= {require("../../static/images/Jstar.jpg")}
  alt= {WorkExperiences.pastExperiences[0].companyName}
/>
```

Then this works.

```
{
"pastExperiences" : [
        {
            "pictures": ["../../static/images/Jstar.jpg","",""],
        },
}
```

I am hoping to load the image from the JSON in the JavaScript React file

Comment: are you sure image directory is correct? use log to confirm

Comment: when I use the require function "<img src={require("../../static/images/Jstar.jpg")}></img>" the image shows up. so it should mean it do exist in the folder. I am new to HTML and react so I'm still learning

Comment: try with `import()` instead of `require()`, see if it works

Comment: or try URL directly instead of using `require` or `import`  `../../static/images/Jstar.jpg` or `../static/images/Jstar.jpg`

Comment: I am trying to use a Json file to load the images, so that I can use recursive to just load the images instead of having to use every single URL specific to the image.